# "dscacheutil -q group -a name admin" returns a user that I can't find

Tags: macos, user-account, administrator

I ran a script that was checking for any other admin users on my mac.

```
dscacheutil -q group -a name admin
```

It returned: `root administrator Temp10`

I can't find the Temp10 user account anywhere. I tried listing all the users using `dscl . list users` but I couldn't find the user account there either.

Maybe it's just a remnant of an old user somewhere? If so how can I remove it from that dscacheutil list?

Comment: What is `dscacheutil -q user -a name Temp10`?  There is always [-flushcache](https://ss64.com/osx/dscacheutil.html) as a last resort.

Comment: `dscacheutil -q user -a name Temp10` gives no output.
I also tried `dscacheutil -flushcache` and then ran the original script and it still shows Temp10

Comment: Bit old but [osxdaily](http://osxdaily.com/2014/11/20/flush-dns-cache-mac-os-x/) says to try `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder;say cache flushed` which (seems to) work on my 10.14 system.

Comment: thanks for that suggestion but Temp10 still shows up after running that command. I'm working on a 10.15.1 system if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

After trying a bunch of different things I had the idea to create a new admin user account called Temp10 manually. And then delete that account. That seems to have resolved the problem. There must have been some remnant of the account left over from something that didn't clean up after it got deleted.